# PHP Error : Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from https://

Tags: php, ssl, soap, wsdl

I'm pretty new at SOAP, but i didn't think this problem was going to give me such a headache. :-)

I have a WSDL at : 
https://qas.sanitel.be/int/QAS_Sanitel_ExtInterfacingSvcs_v2/SanitelServices.asmx?wsdl

Seems to be OK, but it's over https. i think that's where my problem is.

I wrote several PHP scripts i found here on stackoverflow and google to get at least a function list, but anything i try gives me the same error :

I put the script on a wamp server, external host, external with SSL..

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://qas.sanitel.be/int/QAS_Sanitel_ExtInterfacingSvcs_v2/SanitelServices.asmx?wsdl=wsdl1' : failed to load external entity "https://qas.sanitel.be/int/QAS_Sanitel_ExtInterfacingSvcs_v2/SanitelServices.asmx?wsdl=wsdl1" in C:\wamp\www\sanitel.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\sanitel.php(25): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://WS4SNTR...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\sanitel.php on line 25

I have the credentials , tried several authentications, everything gives me this error...

anyone see something i don't ? Thanks a lot !